# Properties of Ring Completion

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ a commutative ring with an arbitrary ideal $I$. Consider the completion $\hat{A}_I := \varprojlim A / I^n$.

I have a few questions about some $length$ relations between $A$ and $\hat{A}_I $:

Why following relations hold:

1. $length_A (\hat{A} / \hat{I}^n) = length_A A /I^n$ (here $\hat{I}$ induced ideal in $\hat{A}$ by $I$)
2. $length_{\hat{A}} (\hat{A} / \hat{I}^n)=0$

The term $length$ I'm working with is described here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IU

Comment: Doesn't 1 and 2 lead to a contradiction, since length of $A/I^n\neq 0$ if $I$ is a proper ideal? Also, I believe the arrow for completion should be $\leftarrow$.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry, we consider here the INVERSE limit.